# How can i completely get rid of a row in my csv file?

Tags: python, csv

Ok , Ive been searching around the site for solutions and I've found a few , but those cases do not work in my favor, mainly because they are using the `'wb'` mode in the `csv` file , that's my argument as to my question is different as well as im using `DictReader` and `Writer`.basically, I want to loop through data in my `csv` file and if the data matches what is put inside of the `delete_entry` i want to completely remove that `line` from the `csv` file. I've come across the idea of just overwriting the unwanted `line` with the data already in the `csv` file, but I'm not sure how to approach that solution. I thought this was a logical solution, but what ends up happening is every line is deleted.

```
import csv
def delete_information_method():
    #a tkinter entry
    global delete_entry
    #opening csv in read
    with open('employees.csv' , 'r') as emp_read:
        #creating our dictreader
        csv_dictreader = csv.DictReader(emp_read)
        #opening csv file again in write mode
        with open ('employees.csv' , 'w') as emp_write:
            #creating our writer
            csv_writer1 = csv.writer(emp_write)
            #our loop to check each line inside of our csv file is equal to what is inside the delete entry
            for line in csv_dictreader:
                if line['employee id'] == str(delete_entry):
                    del line
```

## contents of csv file :

```
first name,last name,email,DOB,adress,position,employee salary,employee id
ronald,colyar,N/A,1-1-2029 ,11245 s. plaski,software dev,233333,233
```

Comment: Either, read in the entire file and then write it out, or read it in and write it out to a different filename.

Comment: @StephenRauch can i see some code ? using what i got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several points here:

- You do need to open the file in `rb`/`wb` mode (if on Python 2) or use the `newline=''` parameter on Python 3 when dealing with CSV files. At least if there is a possibility of newlines appearing in your data.
- You can't open the file for writing while it's still open for reading, especially since you haven't read any data from it at that point.
- You never write anything to the file. The only thing you do is open it in write mode (which erases it as the very first thing).

Better use a different output file:

```
#assuming Python 3
def delete_information_method():
    #a tkinter entry
    global delete_entry
    #opening csv in read
    with open('employees.csv' , 'r', newline='') as emp_read:
        #creating our dictreader
        csv_dictreader = csv.DictReader(emp_read)
        fieldnames = csv_dictreader.fieldnames
        #opening new csv file in write mode
        with open ('employees_out.csv' , 'w', newline='') as emp_write:
            #creating our writer
            csv_writer1 = csv.DictWriter(emp_write, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            csv_writer1.writeheader()
            #our loop to check each line inside of our csv file is equal to what is inside the delete entry
            for line in csv_dictreader:
                if line['employee id'] != str(delete_entry.get()):
                    csv_writer1.writerow(line)
```

If you don't want to do that, read the entire file and then write it afterwards:

```
def delete_information_method():
    #a tkinter entry
    global delete_entry
    #opening csv in read
    with open('employees.csv' , 'r', newline='') as emp_read:
        #creating our dictreader
        csv_dictreader = csv.DictReader(emp_read)
        fieldnames = csv_dictreader.fieldnames
        contents = [line for line in csv_dictreader]
    #opening csv file in write mode
    with open ('employees.csv' , 'w', newline='') as emp_write:
        #creating our writer
        csv_writer1 = csv.DictWriter(emp_write, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer1.writeheader()
        #our loop to check each line inside of our csv file is equal to what is inside the delete entry
        for line in contents:
            if line['employee id'] != str(delete_entry.get()):
                csv_writer1.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Strange. I did forget a line to write the field names, so they should be missing...and I changed the `==` to `!=`, did you notice that?

Comment: update it and u forgot the .get function on the delete_entry for the second  and first

Comment: still having the same problem

Comment: Yes, I haven't been thinking clearly, sorry: Of course we should also be using a DictWriter, otherwise only the fieldnames will be printed (because dictionaries are iterated over by keys, so that's what the standard CSV writer will write). Too early in the morning. I will try to fix this now.

Comment: so basically in lamest terms , we are rewriting over the file excluding the line thats in the delete entry? just to get a clear understanding of whats going on in the second solution

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said. Do not mix input with output. Plus read a documentation on how `DictReader` and `DictWrite` works:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Now working code:

```
def delete_information_method():
    # First, read input
    new_records = []
    with open('employees.csv', 'r') as emp_read:
        csv_dictreader = csv.DictReader(emp_read)
        for record in csv_dictreader:
            # Note: you do not need to mark delete_entry as global
            # Since you are only using it to get and not updating it
            if record['employee id'] != str(delete_entry):
                new_records.append(record)

    # Now you have all records you care about and now you can
    # write it into output
    #
    # BTW, since it is different block than
    # with open('employees.csv'...
    # There you can safely use same file name if you want/need
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as emp_writer:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(
            emp_writer,
            # This is important since you are using dicts to 
            # work with csv
            fieldnames=csv_dictreader.fieldnames
        )
        # Do not forget header row
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        for record in new_records:
            csv_writer.writerow(record)
```